# "could not stat file" error message when running database report

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Though I googled around a lot I couldn't find any post for my problem...

I want to run a database report in PgAdmin and I get the error message

> 'could not stat file ...\xyz_fsm'

As far as I can see this is NOT a permission problem and also NOT a virus scanner issue (like similar posts conclude) - but the _fsm file does simply not exist! (not on any drive!) Strange thing is that all my 4 databases are up and running, but apparently only creating a report doesn't work (same error both via PgAdmin and ngpsql). I'm running Postgres 9.3.1 on Windows 2008 R2.

Anyone any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bug report (#12127) because I can reproduce this behavior and also exclude other possible error sources.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you conlude already more or less could not stat file does mean that the file is not there and so can not be looked at.

If you are sure that it is NOT a permissions Problem then try creating that file empty with an editor and make sure that this file can be writen to, executed killedand blown up by anyone in the world.

Then try it again. The error should now have changed.

But really do check your logs and set them to debug ifneed be. You will find the place where somewhere someone is trying to create that file and is not allowed to.

On Windows Server 2008 I am unfortunately not of that much help if it comes to postgresql on a linux I would be a bit more help. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but looking at the error message in detail I suspect something went wrong with tablespace. The path looks weird: could not stat file "pg_tblspc/16393/PG_9.3_201306121/16394/33248752_fsm": Permission denied - as if tablespace 16394 is within tablespace 16393... also the drive and top level directories are missing in the file path, not sure, but I guess it should look like  could not stat file "D:\pgsql\data\PG_9.3_201306121\16394\33248752_fsm": Permission denied